# onFocus exhibits weird behavior

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onfocus

I'm a little confused by the behavior of the `onFocus` event.  I have a form with several textareas and I want them to perform pretty much the same as `input[:text]` fields, that is, when a user tabs into or clicks a certain field, all of the text in the field is selected.  The documentation on the Mozilla website says that `onFocus` is triggered whenever a user enters a field either via a mouse click or the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, so it seems like the ideal event to use.  However, it doesn't behave as I would expect it to.

I assumed the following code would work:

```
e.addEventListener('focus',function(){e.select()})
```

But it doesn't work.  However, using `onClick` works fine:

```
e.addEventListener('click',function(){e.select()})
```

Except that it only selects the text in the field when the user enters the field via a mouse click and not via the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.  After a little playing around I found that this works:

```
e.addEventListener('focus',function(){setTimeout(function(){e.select()},0)})
```

I've tested this on Safari 7 and Chrome 35.  Firefox 29 kind of works, but I've yet to figure out what it's doing.

Can someone explain what I am missing?

I've included a sample page that illustrates what I've been discussing:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
        var e = document.forms[0].elements
        e[0].value = "fld1: "
        e[0].addEventListener('focus',function(event){
                e[0].value += "onfocus, "
                e[0].select()
            })
        e[1].value = "fld2: "
        e[1].addEventListener('focus',function(event){
                e[1].value += "onfocus, "
                setTimeout(function(){e[1].select()},0)
            })
        e[2].value = "fld3: "
        e[2].addEventListener('click',function(event){
                e[2].value += "onclick, "
                e[2].select()
            })
    }
</script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
<form>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=80></textarea>
    <br/><br/>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=80></textarea>
    <br/><br/>
    <textarea rows=4 cols=80></textarea>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: The default behavior for the "focus" interaction is for the browser to *unselect* the contents of the field. You weren't preventing the default action, after your event handler returned the browser took its normal course of action.

Comment: could you provide a link that explains that?  and, apparently, that action only applies to textarea elements.  text[:input] elements do not exhibit that behavior.

Comment: I can't find anything in a quick read of the W3C spec, but browsers definitely behave that way. And yes, it's specifically a `<textarea>` thing.

Comment: ok, thx.  i'll keep searching.

Comment: Did you try the preventDefault method to stop the browser from doing anything more after your code completes?

Comment: @Pointy I was battling with that in my answer, and even when preventing the default action, it still wouldn't work. I assume that it had something to do with attaching the event listener somehow. Anyhow, I found a solution without having the prevent the default action.

Comment: Any update to this?

Answer (score 0):

In terms of Vanilla JS, the problem most likely lies within attaching the `EventListener` to the proper element(s). This can be done by getting all of the elements (either by class name or similar), loop through them in an array-like format and attach the `EventListener` function that way.

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control auto-selector" value="Some input field text value" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control auto-selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet felis vel lacus auctor, nec sollicitudin leo blandit. Praesent arcu tellus, fringilla id efficitur ut, interdum vitae risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean eleifend dui vel blandit facilisis. Curabitur vel libero ut erat ultricies pretium. Proin congue, orci sed dignissim consequat, nunc massa scelerisque ante, in efficitur est sem ac nulla. Aliquam at est sed ligula lobortis feugiat ut et nisl.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Vanilla JS:**

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('auto-selector');

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
        this.focus();
        this.select();
    });
});
```

**Snippet Example:**

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('auto-selector');

Array.from(elements).forEach(function(element) {
    element.addEventListener("focus", function(e) {
        this.focus();
        this.select();
    });
});
```

```css
textarea.auto-selector {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control auto-selector" value="Some input field text value" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control auto-selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet felis vel lacus auctor, nec sollicitudin leo blandit. Praesent arcu tellus, fringilla id efficitur ut, interdum vitae risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean eleifend dui vel blandit facilisis. Curabitur vel libero ut erat ultricies pretium. Proin congue, orci sed dignissim consequat, nunc massa scelerisque ante, in efficitur est sem ac nulla. Aliquam at est sed ligula lobortis feugiat ut et nisl.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen Example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/abdJyOa).

In the event that you are able / allowed to use jQuery, the solution becomes much easier.

**jQuery:**

```
$('.auto-selector').on("focus", function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```

**Snippet Example:**

```js
$('.auto-selector').on("focus", function() {
    $(this).select();
});
```

```css
textarea.auto-selector {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <input type="text" class="form-control auto-selector" value="Some input field text value" />
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row d-flex justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <textarea class="form-control auto-selector">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse aliquet felis vel lacus auctor, nec sollicitudin leo blandit. Praesent arcu tellus, fringilla id efficitur ut, interdum vitae risus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Aenean eleifend dui vel blandit facilisis. Curabitur vel libero ut erat ultricies pretium. Proin congue, orci sed dignissim consequat, nunc massa scelerisque ante, in efficitur est sem ac nulla. Aliquam at est sed ligula lobortis feugiat ut et nisl.</textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

Codepen example [here](https://codepen.io/mbacode/pen/YzwZVar).

Comment: Use of jquery is not asked for Martin, and is a heavy requirement to add simply to get around text selection. Although your solution does work and will be useful for fans of jquery I guess.

Comment: Edited answer to include Vanilla JS as well. @PeterBrand

Comment: But then the Vanilla JS doesn't work as requested. Try clicking between the text and textareas. When the textarea has no selection, your code selects the entire text. But if the textarea has a selection, the next time you click on it, the browser deselects the text, after your code has run.  I suspect jquery delays the focus code till after the browser does its thing.

Comment: *" I have a form with several textareas and I want them to perform pretty much the same as input[:text] fields, that is, when a user tabs into or clicks a certain field, all of the text in the field is selected."* @PeterBrand this is what OP asked for, and this is exactly what happens in my code.

Comment: My bad Martin, I tested the vanilla JS again and now it works as expected in FireFox. Can't remember what I used before. I see now in the onFocus event your run the focus() event again, which will trigger the browser's deselect-code, then you do the select(). I guess that at the end of that the browser figures the element already has the focus and doesn't trigger its deselect-code.  One way of doing it, but the preventDefault would still be simpler and perhaps more reliable cross-browser.

Comment: @PeterBrand if you want to compliment the answer with another solution, feel free to. I'll credit you. You can link a codepen or similar with the solution if you'd like. I tried the `preventDefault();` method, and it didn't work for me in Chrome (didn't test anything else).